# MongoDB: count number of matches for OR condition query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Given a MongoDB with nested documents

```
collection = client.test.or_example
new_documents = [
{'_id': 1, 'proportions':{'A': 0.3, 'B': 0.1}},
{'_id': 2, 'proportions':{'C': 0.3, 'D': 0.1}},
{'_id': 3, 'proportions':{'A': 0.3, 'C': 0.3}},
{'_id': 4, 'proportions':{'B': 0.1, 'D': 0.3}},
{'_id': 5, 'proportions':{'A': 0.1, 'B': 0.3}}]
collection.insert_many(new_documents)
```

I can construct a query that uses OR conditions

```
collection.find({'$or': [{'proportions.A': {'$gt': 0.2}},
                         {'proportions.B': {'$gt': 0.2}},
                         {'proportions.C': {'$gt': 0.2}}]}
```

which returns four documents (id's 1, 2, 3, 5). Now I'd like to sort these documents by the number of OR conditions they satisfy, so 3, 1, 2, 5 (with respective number of matches 2, 1, 1, 1).

I've been experimenting with counting the number of OR matches in an aggregation pipeline, but can't get it to work. I've managed to create a related field "coverage", but my current try for "number_matches" isn't valid syntax.

```
results = collection.aggregate([
    {
        '$match': {'$or': [{'proportions.A': {'$gt': 0.2}}, 
                           {'proportions.B': {'$gt': 0.2}}, 
                           {'proportions.C': {'$gt': 0.2}}]}
    },
    {
        '$addFields':
        {
            'coverage': {'$sum': [ '$proportions.A', '$proportions.B', '$proportions.C']},
            'number_matches': {'$sum': [ {'cond': [{'proportions.A': {'$gt': 0.2}}, 1, 0]},
                                         {'cond': [{'proportions.B': {'$gt': 0.2}}, 1, 0]},
                                         {'cond': [{'proportions.C': {'$gt': 0.2}}, 1, 0]} ] }
        }
    },
    {
        '$sort': {'number_matches': -1}
    }
])
```

Also, my current try feels rather convoluted, so I hope there might be a simpler way.

I'm looking for a solution that works with MongoDB 3.4, but in case there's a more elegant or faster solution for 3.6, I'd also be interested in that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you will need to add an intermediate step

- Execute the $match
- Create a match for each proportion (matchA, matchB, matchC)
- Sum the matches